# Adding dataframes and dividing resultant based on availability

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I want to add two dataframes which I can achieve by add function.
Now I want to divide each value of resultant dataframe based on whether respective value was present in initial dataframes(df1,df2,df3). For eg.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]], index =['A','B'], columns = ['C','D'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[11,12], [13,14]], index = ['A','B'], columns = ['D','E'])
df3 = df1.add(df2, fill_value=0)
```

This would result in a df like

```
     C   D     E
A  1.0  13  12.0
B  3.0  17  14.0
```

I require a df like:

```
     C    D     E
A  1.0  6.5  12.0
B  3.0  8.5  14.0
```

because D column is found in both dataframes, I divide those values by 2.
Can anyone please provide a generic solution, assuming I need to add more than 2 dataframes (so the division factor also changes) and have more than 100 columns in each dataframe.

Answer (score 5):

We can concatenate all DFs horizontally in one step:

```
In [13]: df = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1).fillna(0)
```

this yields:

```
In [15]: df
Out[15]:
   C  D   D   E
A  1  2  11  12
B  3  4  13  14
```

now we can group by columns, calculating average (`mean`):

```
In [14]: df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).mean()
Out[14]:
     C    D     E
A  1.0  6.5  12.0
B  3.0  8.5  14.0
```

or we can do it in one step (thanks [@jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45731261/adding-dataframes-and-dividing-resultant-based-on-availability/45731352?noredirect=1#comment78421996_45731352)):

```
In [60]: pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1).fillna(0).groupby(level=0, axis=1).mean()
Out[60]:
     C    D     E
A  1.0  6.5  12.0
B  3.0  8.5  14.0
```

**Timing:**

```
In [38]: df1 = pd.concat([df1] * 10**5, ignore_index=True)

In [39]: df2 = pd.concat([df2] * 10**5, ignore_index=True)

In [40]: %%timeit
    ...: df = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1).fillna(0)
    ...: df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).mean()
    ...:
63.4 ms ± 2.39 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [41]: %%timeit
    ...: s = pd.Series(np.concatenate([df1.columns, df2.columns])).value_counts()
    ...: df1.add(df2, fill_value=0).div(s)
    ...:
28.7 ms ± 712 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [42]: %%timeit
    ...: pd.concat([df1,df2]).mean(level = 0)
    ...:
65.5 ms ± 555 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [43]: df1.shape
Out[43]: (200000, 2)

In [44]: df2.shape
Out[44]: (200000, 2)
```

**Current winner:** @jezrael (`28.7 ms ± 712 µs`) - congratulations!

Comment: instead `df.columns` is better `level=0`

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are trying to compute a mean. Don't do too many operations with the dataframe methods and individual columns if you can help it, as it's slow.

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2]) # concatenate all your dataframes together
df.mean(level = 0)
```

The second line computes the mean along the vertical axis (`axis = 0` by default), and `level = 0` tells pandas to get the mean of each unique index.

Comment: `pd.concat([df1,df2]).mean(0).to_dict()` is not the same as `pd.concat([df1,df2]).mean(level=0).to_dict()`. The first positional argument of `.mean()` is `axis`.

Comment: oh, my bad, apologize! Your solution is way better than mine then... :-) I'd also do it in one line...

Answer (score 4):

Faster solution is divide by size of columns:

```
s = pd.Series(np.concatenate([df1.columns, df2.columns])).value_counts()
print (s)
C    1
D    2
E    1
dtype: int64

df3 = df1.add(df2, fill_value=0).div(s)
print (df3)
     C    D     E
A  1.0  6.5  12.0
B  3.0  8.5  14.0
```

**Timings** (with 100 columns like OP mentioned):

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 100000
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(N, 100)))
df1.columns = 'col' + df1.columns.astype(str)
df2 = df1.mul(10)

#MaxU solution 
In [127]: %timeit (pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1).fillna(0).groupby(level=0, axis=1).mean())
1 loop, best of 3: 952 ms per loop

#Ken Wei solution
In [128]: %timeit (pd.concat([df1,df2]).mean(level = 0))
1 loop, best of 3: 895 ms per loop

#jez solution
In [129]: %timeit (df1.add(df2, fill_value=0).div(pd.Series(np.concatenate([df1.columns, df2.columns])).value_counts()))
10 loops, best of 3: 161 ms per loop
```

More general solution:

If have list of `DataFrames`, is possible chaning like:

```
df = df1.add(df2, fill_value=0).add(df3, fill_value=0)
```

but better is use `reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce

dfs = [df1,df2, df3]
s = pd.Series(np.concatenate([x.columns for x in dfs])).value_counts()
df5 = reduce(lambda x, y: x.add(y, fill_value=0), dfs).div(s)
```